# Java Hashtable containsValue() not working

Tags: java, string, text, hashtable

I'm trying to code a spellchecker using a hashtable of dictionary words. I'm currently trying to compare  words from a text document to a value in the hash table to see if it's spelled correctly, but no matter what I do, the containsValue() method always returns false even when I know it's not.

```
public class SpellChecker {

    private Hashtable<Integer, Wrapper> words;
    private ArrayList<Wrapper> parsedFile;

    SpellChecker() {
        words = new Hashtable<Integer, Wrapper>();
        parsedFile = new ArrayList<Wrapper>();
    }

    public void createDict(String inputFile) throws IOException {
        FileReader input = new FileReader(inputFile);
        BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(input);
        String myLine = null;
        int i = 0;
        while ((myLine = bufRead.readLine()) != null)
        {   
            Wrapper my_line = new Wrapper(myLine);
            words.put(i,my_line);
            i++;
        }
        bufRead.close();
    }

    public ArrayList<Wrapper> readFile(String inputFile) throws IOException {
        FileReader input = new FileReader(inputFile);
        BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(input);
        String myLine = null;
        Wrapper[] array_file;

        while ((myLine = bufRead.readLine()) != null)
        {   
            String[] arrayFile = myLine.split(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayFile.length; i++) {
                array_file = new Wrapper[arrayFile.length];
                arrayFile[i] = arrayFile[i].toLowerCase();

                Wrapper my_line = new Wrapper(arrayFile[i]);
                array_file[i] = my_line;
                parsedFile.add(array_file[i]);
            }
        }

        bufRead.close();
        return parsedFile;
    }

    public ArrayList<Wrapper> getParsedFile(){
        return parsedFile;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> checkMisspellings() {
        ArrayList<String> misspelled = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i<parsedFile.size(); i++) {
            if (!words.containsValue(parsedFile.get(i))) {
                misspelled.add(parsedFile.get(i).backToString());
            }
        }
        return misspelled;
    }
}
```

I looked at some answers online that said it might be because containsValue() compares addresses, so I made a wrapper class for the String values but it still isn't working.

```
public class Wrapper {

    public String x;

    public Wrapper(String x){
        this.x=x;
    }

    public String backToString() {
        return x;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
   if(o == null) return false;
   if(!(o instanceof Wrapper)) return false;
   final Wrapper p = (Wrapper) o;
   if(p.x.equals(this.x)) return true;
   return false;
}

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
      int hash = 3;
      hash = 53 * hash + x.length();
      return hash;
    }
}
```

the misspelled arrayList is supposed to only contain words that aren't found in the hashtable, but it always just returns all the original words. What am I doing wrong??
Here's some sample input/output:

```
input: hellos my name Ann corral mlks please spell correct 
output: [��hellos, my, name, ann, corral, mlks, please, spell, correct, ]
```

the text file I'm using for the dictionary looks something like this:

```
corralled
corralling
corrals
correct
correctable
corrected
correcter
correctest
correcting
```

Comment: '... it might be because containsValue() compares addresses': it isn't, and it doesn't. See the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsValue-java.lang.Object-).

Comment: That's what I thought but it doesn't work no matter what I try and I can't seem to figure out why :((

Comment: What is the purpose of `array_file = new Wrapper[arrayFile.length];` in your loop?

Comment: It was to make a new array of type Wrapper so that I could compare them to the hashtable Wrapper values -- even when I didn't have the Wrapper class and worked with Strings, though, the code still didn't work so I don't think it makes a difference

Comment: But in each iteration you are creating a *`new Wrapper[arrayFile.length];`* in which you are setting and using only `[i]` element. This suggest it shouldn't be an array at all.

Comment: that's true, but I think that's a matter of space/efficiency since the result turns out the same

Comment: "*I looked at some answers online that said it might be because containsValue() compares addresses, so I made a wrapper class for the String values but it still isn't working.*" that shouldn't be the case, so Wrapper class shouldn't be needed. To help you with your code based on Strings we would need to see it. Also is using `Hashtable` mandatory? If not consider HashMap which usually is preferred if there is no concurrency issues.

Comment: Another thing we need to see is *how* you are using this code. What input you provide, when, what results you expected (why) and what you got instead?

Comment: With your current code I cannot reproduce your problem. I tried with `SpellChecker sp = new SpellChecker(); sp.createDict("dict.txt"); sp.readFile("input.txt"); System.out.println(sp.checkMisspellings());` and the words from dict.txt were correctly removed.

Comment: Also `output: [��hellos,` suggests that encoding of your input file uses BOM (Byte Order Mark) character which as you see is treated as part of string. Consider changing encoding to something without BOM.

Answer (score 2):

Change `p.x==this.x` to `p.x.equals(this.x)` in your `equals()` method.

For more info, learn about [how to compare Strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Comment: thanks for the answer! I tried that and it still doesn't work :(

Comment: @AnnaLi can you update your question with some sample input and output? perhaps you are looking for case-insensitive equality, in which case you need to use `equalsIgnoreCase()`

Comment: I updated it! I don't think it's a matter of case since the values look exactly the same but I'll try